# Passing a SeekBar value into mysql database

Tags: android, mysql

I am writing a simple program where user pushes the seekbar to certain level and than that level is saved into mysql database. How can i get the seekbar value out of the method and post it? I am stuck since i am new to android programming. Any help here would be much apritiated.

I know the problem at the moment is that the seekbar is int value and i am trying to use string. How to change the below public void poslji to use int instead of string.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    private TextView test;
    private TextView textView;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private SeekBar seekBar;


   @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
       setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

       seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById( seek_bar_id );


       initializeVariables();

       textView.setText( "Jakost bolečine: " + seekBar.getProgress() + "/" + seekBar.getMax() );

       seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener( new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
           int progress = 0;

           @Override
           public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progresValue, boolean fromUser) {
               progress = progresValue;
           }

           @Override
           public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
           }

           @Override
           public void onStopTrackingTouch(final SeekBar seekBar) {

               textView.setText( "Jakost bolečine: " + progress + "/" + seekBar.getMax() );
               if (progress == 0) {

                   imageView.setImageResource( R.drawable.no_pain );
               }
               if (progress <= 2 && progress >= 1) {
                   imageView.setImageResource( R.drawable.little_pain );
                   Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Blaga bolečina!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
               }

               if (progress <= 4 && progress >= 3) {
                   imageView.setImageResource( R.drawable.moderata_pain );
                   Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Zmerna bolečina!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
               }

               if (progress <= 6 && progress >= 5) {
                   imageView.setImageResource( R.drawable.severe_pain );
                   Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Srednja bolečina!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
               }

               if (progress <= 8 && progress >= 7) {
                   imageView.setImageResource( R.drawable.very_severe_pain );
                   Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Dokaj močna bolečina!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
               }

               if (progress <= 10 && progress >= 9) {
                   imageView.setImageResource( R.drawable.worst_pain );
                   Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Zelo močna bolečina!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
               }

               test.setText( "" + progress );


           }

       } );


   }
    private void initializeVariables() {
        seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek_bar_id);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jakost_bolecin_id);
        test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);
        imageView=(ImageView)findViewById( R.id.slika_bolecine );

    }
```

Stuck on this part (this continues from the above code):

```
    public void poslji (View view){

          String poslji_data = seekBar.getText().toString();
          String type ="Poslji";
        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
        BackgroundWorker.execute(type,poslji_data);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert a String to an Integer use:

```
int integerHere = Integer.parseInt(stringToConvert);
```